# TYPO3: what is the configuration for RTE linkhandler in v8?

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, rte

with the new RTE in TYPO3 v8 I miss the option to have editors work with classes ... in v7 with the rtehtmlarea I added personal classes trough typoscript:

```
RTE.classesAnchor {
    inverselink {
        class = inverse
        type = page
        titleText = New default title
        target = _blank
    }
}

RTE.default {
    proc.allowedClasses := addToList(inverse)
    buttons {
        link {
            properties.class.allowedClasses := addToList(inverse)
        }
    }
}
```

---

but now I'd be happy to just have the option to write one in the wizard ... *(I use v8.7.8)*

**these are the options for a title link or image link:** *(with css_class)*
[image: linkhandler for title or image link]

**these are the options offered in the RTE wizard:**
[image: linkhandler for CkEditor]

Comment: This one might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596767/how-to-define-custom-class-title-and-target-in-link-browser-for-content-elemen/43601572#43601572

Comment: Ghanshyam Bhava - I did apply your solution, that did activate the linkhandler, thank you, but this issue is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82865 and will hopefully be fixed in the next release.

If you define this in your yaml preset is will work.

Comment: It seems you have the exact picture, and with all that I studied regarding, your patch looks spot-on ... I did delete cashes and whatever, but no result ... I work with EXT:T3SBootstrap and entered your 'snippet' into its default.yaml

Comment: Are you sure that default.yaml is used/loaded for the field you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

This Link helps me a lot. Link classes for `ckeditor` in `TYPO3`

https://www.thomaskieslich.de/blog/135-links-im-ckeditor-mit-eigenen-css-klassen/